# Why is apt update complaining about a repository that isn't in sources.list not having a Release file?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 18.04, repository

When I run `sudo apt update`, I get this:

```
E: The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu bionic-getdeb Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I do not have these repositories. Here's my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412)]/ zesty main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security multiverse
```

I tried `sudo apt-add-repository --remove http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu`, but it returned no output, and when I tried `sudo apt update` again, I got the same error.

I'm hoping to get this error to go away, but I don't know how. Is that possible? What can I do?

Comment: Additionally 17.04 is EOL so your current sources list is pretty useless & generally askubuntu does not support questions on EOL releases posted after EOL date

Comment: @N0rbert called it. Thank you. Respond with that as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer so you can get your Internet points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have *archive.getdeb.net* in some file inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

As [getdeb.net does not have Release file for Bionic](http://www.getdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/#how_to_install) (it supports only 17.04), you should remove corresponding `*.list` file from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory.

---

Wine PPA [does not have packages for Bionic](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), you should remove it with its packages by

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```